# QGIS 3.22 on Windows 8.1 ->Python Error on Startup

Tags: qgis, python, installation, windows-8

My installation of QGIS 3.22 on Windows 8.1 finished without any error. During startup I get the error message that the SIP-Modul cannot be loaded and that the Python support will be disabled:

```
Das SIP-Modul konnte nicht geladen werden. Die Python-Unterstützung wird abgeschaltet.
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\__init__.py", line 76, in 
    os.add_dll_directory(p)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\os.py", line 1111, in add_dll_directory
    cookie = nt._add_dll_directory(path) OSError: [WinError 87] Falscher Parameter: '.'
Python-Version:
3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS-Version:
3.22.0-Białowieża 'Białowieża', d9022691f1
Python-Pfad: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/Tobias/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python', 'C:/Users/Tobias/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\bin\\python39.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

I'm wondering how the "." sneaked into the Python Path `C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis_init_.py`

Comment: How did you install? OSGeo4W v2 does not support 32bit as mentioned on the QGIS download site mentions. There, you also find that "Windows 7 no longer works as we are now using Python 3.9, which dropped support for it." Maybe one of these or a similar compatibility issue?

Comment: I've used the 64-Bit installer "QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.22.0-1.msi" on Windows 8.1. I know that Windows 7 is not supported, but I haven't found a note saying that Windows 8.1 isn't supported too.